# imap vs. map in grequests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, gevent, grequests

As far as I know the difference between `map` and `imap` is that `map` waits for all requests to finish and then returns the ordered data. Whereas `imap` returns data immediately and order less.

When I use:

```
urls = [...some_data...]
rs = (grequests.get(u,, hooks=dict(response=callback_f)) for u in urls)
r = grequests.map(rs)
```

the hook is used as soon as all requests finish, and the callback function is called.

When I use:

```
urls = [...some_data...]
rs = (grequests.get(u,, hooks=dict(response=callback_f)) for u in urls)
r = grequests.imap(rs)
```

then not a single request is sent.

According to the documentation map and imap have excatly the same API.

Is this the expected behavior? Should I not use hooks with imap?
I am using Python 3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far as I know the difference between `map` and `imap` is that `map` waits for all requests to finish and then returns the ordered data. Whereas `imap` returns data immediately and order less.

That's not really True. `map` does all requests immediatly and returns the result (this can take a while so that's why you probably said "waits for all requests to finish").

However `imap` returns a generator and does the requests **only** on demand. So you have to start iterating over the generator before requests are sent. Loop over the generator to get the results:

```
for single_request in r:
    # so something with "single_request"
```

Comment: So there is basically no way to make `imap` issue all the requests concurrently?

Comment: It has a parameter `size` to specify how many requests should be done concurrently. At least according to [`grequests.imap` on "Nullege Python Samples"](http://nullege.com/codes/search/grequests.imap)

Comment: @MSeifert also i use `.imap(..., size=1)` with huge requests so they are sent one after another in the background.

Comment: By default `size=2` in `imap` and `size=None` in `map` (uses this parameter for throttling) https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/blob/master/grequests.py

Comment: `each iteration only one request is made` is not exactly correct. The number of requests handled each iteration is not guaranteed, but will be less than or equal to the `size` argument. When the number of _results_ awaiting the reader is greater than `size`, the greenlets will block, awaiting the reader before making more requests.